# new Breakpoints are created, unwanted!

Tags: visual-studio-2008, breakpoints

I am running VS 2008 pro.
my solution file has two project.
Break points location are saved in .suo file which I delete it before opening the projects.
even if I go to the debug menu, there is no active break point listed in there.
but when I run the program, It goes to a breakpoint ( not an exception or anything) a break point, the same big red circle of break points I mean... who set that break point in there? I dont know! it did not even exist before running the program!

Answer (score 0):

go to menu debug -> delete all break points

Comment: I have done that. There is no break point at all before I RUN the program. then that break point is created out of no where!

Comment: ok, can you do this trick?, change the solution path, put it in another folder and try to open it again, and tell me the result